# how to define list of string on gorm model?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

this is my model

```
type Ticket struct {
    gorm.Model

    PassengerName string         `json:"passenger_name"`
    Price         uint64         `json:"price"`
    Seat          pq.StringArray `gorm:"type:string[]" json:"seat"`
}
```

gorm.io/driver/postgres@v1.3.1/migrator.go:118 ERROR: type "string[]" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42704)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s no string data type in postgre. Change string[] to text[]

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good approach. You should make a separate table for it

Ticket Table:

```
type Ticket struct {
    gorm.Model

    PassengerName string         `json:"passenger_name"`
    Price         uint64         `json:"price"`
    Seat          []Seat         `json:"seat" gorm:"foreignKey:SeatId"` }
```

Seat Table:

```
 type Seat struct {
    gorm.Modal

    SeatId  serial `json:seat_id`
    Seat    string `json:"seat"`}
```

Comment: I understand about your concern and this is very make sense but unfortunate this array of string to display to the user and 'seat' mechanism by itself is in schedule table so this is just placeholder